# Issue with super init while inheriting from Langchain class

Tags: python, class, oop, langchain

I'm trying to write an LLM class as below:

```
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

class LLM:
    def __init__(self,model_name):
        super().__init__(model_name=model_name)
        self.model_name = model_name  

class OpenAILLM(LLM,ChatOpenAI):
    def __init__(self,model_name):
        super().__init__(model_name=model_name)
        self.model_name = model_name
```

which works fine but when I try to add another variable in `__init__` of `OpenAILLM` class as below

```
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

class LLM:
    def __init__(self,model_name):
        super().__init__(model_name=model_name)
        self.model_name = model_name  

class OpenAILLM(LLM,ChatOpenAI):
    def __init__(self,model_name):
        super().__init__(model_name=model_name)
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.var = 'var'
```

The object creation for `OpenAILLM` fails and gives `ValueError: "OpenAILLM" object has no field "var"`

Can anyone help me how I can add more variables?

Another thing I tried is the `get_var` function define below works but the `set_var` function defined below gives same error as above

```
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

class LLM():
    var = 1
    def __init__(self,model_name):
        super().__init__(model_name=model_name)
        self.model_name = model_name  

class OpenAILLM(LLM,ChatOpenAI):
    def __init__(self,model_name):
        super().__init__(model_name=model_name)
        self.model_name = model_name
    def get_var(self):
        return self.var
    def set_var(self, var):
        print('self var',self.var)
        self.var = var
        return True
```

The **mro** of OpenAILLM is as below

```
(__main__.OpenAILLM,
 __main__.LLM,
 langchain_openai.chat_models.base.ChatOpenAI,
 langchain_core.language_models.chat_models.BaseChatModel,
 langchain_core.language_models.base.BaseLanguageModel,
 langchain_core.runnables.base.RunnableSerializable,
 langchain_core.load.serializable.Serializable,
 pydantic.v1.main.BaseModel,
 pydantic.v1.utils.Representation,
 langchain_core.runnables.base.Runnable,
 typing.Generic,
 abc.ABC,
 object)
```

I think this has to do something with pydantic, but I'm not sure. And I don't know how to resolve it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `__slots__` attribute defined on the class `OpenAILLM` (by Pydantic, which I'm not familiar with).

Refer to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots to see how `__slots__` works.

Simply said, if a `__slots__` is defined on a class, its members are set in stone and you may not add additional members to its **direct** instances. And I believe that `ChatOpenAI` is not meant to be subclassed, so just avoid that usage.